# how to create an alternate second factor in IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I built a 2 factor app in aspnetcore 2.0 and tried to add an alternate second factor. To do that I needed to add a simple query on the user in TTokenType. In spite of all the text about IdentityUser being extensible, I could find no way to add a method to this table without rebuilding the entire DB context. Can anyone tell me if there is any way to extend the user token without rebuilding the entire database context?

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: I have created a pull request to add 2factor code to ID Server4 that will run as deployed https://github.com/TomCJones/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity I have not finished code to add additional factors after the first as that is the point of this request.